# Data Validation in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, validation, ssis

Im new to SSIS. I want to develop package for data validation.

FirstName

1. Mandatory   field checking: if Null, reject the record

   2. If field length > 50, then reject the record

SSN

1. If field length > 12, then reject the record

   2. If SSN is not in valid format, issue warning and process rhe record   without SSN value.
   3. Valid format: 9 digit numeric values should present after striping off   all non-numeric characters.
   4. Only send 9 digits to MDM

Like these I have 30 rules. And I have to show the error msg if the validation fails like "Mandatory feild is missing" for some rules.I need send the reject record to seperate table. And if one rule is fail for one record it should not check the remaining rule. it go to reject table. Please help me to build a package.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd use a conditional switch initially to filter some of your failed records but with 30 rules it might be an idea to look into using an input/output column script element to analyse the data and set a fail flag for each record. This could then be filtered by one conditional split. See [http://www.sqlis.com/sqlis/post/The-Script-Component-as-a-Transformation.aspx

Comment: This question is too broad.   Please narrow it to a specific technique that you don't know how to do, and show your attempt to research the question before posting it.

Comment: The general approach I would take is to create boolean flags in your data flow, via a Derived Column. RejectName and formula of `len([FirstName]) > 50`  Then you can use a conditional split to route bad names to an alternate location. Lather, rinse, repeat. Some of these will be more challenging - SSN not in valid format? might be better computed via a .NET script task than a derived column, etc

Answer (score 2):

> Like these I have 30 rules.

It would be far easier to maintain these rules if the SSIS package loaded this data into a 'staging' table without validating, then executed a Stored Procedure that iterated through these rules and acted accordingly.